# Fatal error initializing plugin com.google.gct.core Google Cloud Tools plugin for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-tools, google-cloud-intellij

After I upgrade Google Cloud Tools plugin for IntelliJ (Ultimate 2017.2) to version 18.3.1, I cannot open my project anymore. The message show as below:

```
Cannot load project:
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException:
Fatal error initializing plugin com.google.gct.core
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: Most likely the plugin is not compatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2. You should file an issue in the plugin issue tracker: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about the breakage. We have a fix to this in our latest [alpha](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-google-cloud-tools/update/44463).  Expect this rolled out to everyone today or tomorrow. We will broaden CI coverage to try to catch these before releases.

Comment: The fix is now rolled out in [version 18.3.2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-google-cloud-tools/update/44471)